# Errors Updating Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mobius

I'm trying to update my ruby gems, I had to go the manual route, download > unpack > CD there, the run: ruby setup.rb

To here I was good to go; now however, when trying to update said gems, or when I try to install the mobius network client, I get the following:

```
 C:\Windows\System32>gem update
 Updating installed gems
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
 timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

 C:\Windows\System32>gem install mobius-client
 ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mobius-client' (>= 0), here is why:
 Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out 
 (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Is this something wrong on my side?

Comment: Can you reach the host from your network? Is https://api.rubygems.org/ reachable in your browser? Do you have a firewall rule blocking outbound access for `ruby`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request timed out, you may have a network problem, eg. proxy, dns, firewall, routing, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the firewall.